# Is it possible to capture a screenshot of a widget while the device screen is off?

Tags: android

For an app I'm trying to make I need to periodically capture screenshots of a widget (which my app would be the host of). But I want these screenshots to be captured without waking up the screen.

Essentially I want to refresh the widget, capture screenshot and then send it over the Internet while the phone screen is off.

Edit: **Is it possible to load a widget, and then access its view (in order to generate a screenshot of the view) all while the phone's screen is off / locked?**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to so long as you have an instance of the view. I'm not 100% sure the view's canvas remains drawn with the screen off though. Worth a shot. Here's some code I use to grab view screenshots over the web (note the compression differences for different view sizes)

```
    public static byte[] captureScreenshot(View view) throws JSONException {
        //maybe do something with filename
        String fileName = null;
        try {
            // create bitmap screen capture
            Bitmap bitmap;
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            Bitmap.CompressFormat compressionFormat;
            int filename = view.getId();
            if (filename == -1) {
                filename = 1010;
            }
            if (getBitMapSize(bitmap) > 750000) {
                compressionFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
                fileName = String.valueOf(filename) + ".jpg";
            } else {
                compressionFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
                fileName = String.valueOf(filename) + ".png";
            }

            bitmap.compress(compressionFormat, 60, outputStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error creating screenshot: ");
        }
        return byte[];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Will be helpful for getting the screenshot once I can get the view. Still need assistance in whether I can load a widget and get its view while the phone's screen is off / locked.

Comment: Loading the widget will be problematic. I really don't see how you could do that in a Service.

Comment: What if the widget has already been previously loaded? Could I refresh it, and get it's view in a service?